# How to properly build a search bar using Riverpod providers?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I am using `Riverpod` for state management in my Shopping List app. For the Products screen, I would like to add a real-time search bar so the user can filter certain products.

I am using `SQFlite` for the database, together with the `Repository` pattern to access it.
Here is the code I manage to write so far, but it doesn't return anything in the search bar.

```
final productProvider = FutureProvider<Map<String, dynamic>?>((ref) async {
  final searchText = ref.watch(searchTextProvider);
  final repository = Repository<Product>("Product");

  if (searchText.isNotEmpty) {
    final result = await repository.getByName(searchText);
    return result;
  }
  return null;
});

final searchTextProvider = StateProvider<String>((ref) => '');

class ProductScreen extends ConsumerWidget {
  const ProductScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final productsAsyncValue = ref.watch(productProvider);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Tela de Produtos'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TextField(
            onChanged: (value) {
               ref.read(searchTextProvider);
            },
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Pesquisar',
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: productsAsyncValue.when(
              data: (data) {
                if (data != null) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      final product = data[index];
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text(product['name']),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                } else {
                  return Text('Nenhum resultado encontrado');
                }
              },
              loading: () => CircularProgressIndicator(),
              error: (error, stackTrace) => Text('Erro: $error'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the code for `getByName` in my Repository, should that be the problem:

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>?> getByName(String name) async {
    final map = await dbProvider.db.query(
      tableName,
      where: 'name = ?',
      whereArgs: [name],
    );
    if (map.isNotEmpty) {
      return map.first;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work fine, just change this code:

```
onChanged: (value) {
  ref.read(searchTextProvider.notifier).update((_) => value);
},
```

Also, it may be necessary to return some custom state, which can be implemented using `sealed` classes or the good old `freezed`. You can define loading status, data, empty data, error, other specific cases for convenient processing in the widget. (even though it's still good)